# Is it possible to disable a marketplace extension in some Azure Devops projects only?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-marketplace

We are a large organization with different needs using a single Azure Devops organization with lots of projects. Over time lots of different marketplace extensions are being added but most of our projects do not need them and make the menu and the UX clumsy while they are beneficial for others.

Is it possible to disable some extensions in some projects only or are extensions only configurable for an entire organization?

Comment: Below answers are correct, for now extensions are only configurable for an entire organization. You can share your feedback in links from Flex's answer to share your idea, product team would consider about that :)

Comment: Still no solution to disable extensions on the team project level?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately @Chrizzo answer is correct.

There already are a few feature requests for this:
[extensions-scoped-at-a-project-level](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/537563/extensions-scoped-at-a-project-level.html)
[allow-extensions-to-be-installed-only-in-projects](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/407517/allow-extensions-to-be-installed-only-in-projects.html)

Feel free to upvote them.

Answer (score 5):

We have same problem => Short answer: No, not possible :(
Only configurable for organization.